# How to sketch the waveform of the voltage across capacitor and find equation that describes it?

Tags: circuit-analysis, step-response

Below DC voltage source, a switch, resistor and capacitor. At time \$t=0\$, \$C\$ has zero voltage across it and switch is closed.

1. How do I sketch waveform of voltage across capacitor v/s time and give the equation that describes it?

I knew it may be something like $$V = \frac{Q}{C} = \frac{1}{C}\int_0^T i(t) dt$$ but the waveform is supposed to be \$V\$ is proportional to the area under the \$i(t)\$ graph. The \$i(t)\$ graph is a straight line parallel to the t-axis (step function). So \$V\$ will be proportional to the area of the rectangle whose borders are \$t=0, t=T, i=0\$ and \$i=I\$.

2. What if I change the value of \$R_1\$ to \$2R\$, does that change the response?

[image]

Comment: The time constant or logarithmic charge/discharge rate is easily calculated. See https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/rc/rc_1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The voltage across the capacitor can be found using Laplace transform:

$$\text{V}_\text{C}\left(t\right)=\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{\frac{\hat{\text{u}}}{\text{s}}}{\text{R}+\frac{1}{\text{sC}}}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\right]_{\left(t\right)}\tag1$$